# Why did I have to edit /etc/lsb-release to get apt-get to work?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, apt

I can't open the software sources window from the software center. I can't use apt-get add-apt-repository (and other things).

The error I get with add-apt-repository is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 160, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 584, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 87, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException("Error: could not find a "
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template
```

My old /etc/lsb-release looks like:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu quantal (Development branch)"
```

I changed it to be:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu precise"
```

And suddenly things "work" again. I don't trust it, since I'm effecitvely lying that I have an earlier version. Why did I have to make this change? What can I do to get things working in a more sane fashion?

Answer (score 1):

This will have changed which repositories apt-get was fetching software from. Previously it will have been trying to fetch software from the Development branch of quantals repositories. I would try editing the file to look like this:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu quantal"
```

After editing the file run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`, and see if apt-get isntalling works.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I then did a dist upgrade (since quantal is out now) which changed the file to look like yours (only difference is DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10") and apt-get works. Got me why.

Comment: Ubuntu Neon 20.04 user here. Changing `/etc/lsb-release` didn't help me. I had to change `/usr/lib/os-release` instead. Update can be verified by running `lsb_release -idsa`